# Same content should show on changing window orientation in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

My website has responsive design, I am loading a page in mobile browser in which many images are displayed one below another. It looks fine, when orientation is changed then everything is resized and displayed properly but different content is shown than what was shown before changing orientation

For example, if there are 5 images displaying one below another in mobile browser and currently 2nd image is displaying and then after changing orientation it shows 3rd image instead of 2nd

I am currently using this::
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />`

Plese help

Answer (score 0):

For flexible layouts it’s more practical to base your viewport width on the device in question without setting the zooming parameter. Try the following instead:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```